# CSV writing data beside each other

Tags: java, android, csv

I am writing to CSV file the BLE scanned results. What I am doing currently is writing all the data one below another. 
The data consists of device name, rssi and mac address. For example, the CSV file looks like this -

```
DeviceA -85 DS:DA:AB:2B:B4:AE
DeviceB -100 2C:18:0B:2B:96:9E
DeviceA -85 DS:DA:AB:2B:B4:AE
```

My requireemnt is to write like this -

```
DeviceA -85 DS:DA:AB:2B:B4:AE DeviceB -100 2C:18:0B:2B:96:9E
DeviceA -85 DS:DA:AB:2B:B4:AE
```

After the last column of device A, I need to start with new column of device B instead of writing below device A.
Also for Device C, I want to write it beside Device C...And so on. Here is my code for writing to CSV.

```
public final String DATA_SEPARATOR = ",";
    public final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System
            .getProperty("line.separator");

          try {

                fileName = "test.csv";


               path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "Documents";


                path += File.separatorChar + "SampleApp";
                File file = new File(path, fileName);

                new File(path).mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();

                fileStream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

                fileStream.write("sep= " + DATA_SEPARATOR + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fileStream = null;
            }

 private void writeElements(Object... elements) throws IOException {


            if (fileStream != null) {
                for (Object o : elements) {
                    fileStream.write(o.toString());
                    fileStream.write(DATA_SEPARATOR);
                }
                fileStream.write(LINE_SEPARATOR);
            }

 }
```

`writeElements(btDeviceName, btRSSIValue, btMacId)` is called from `bluetoothScan()` method every now and then.

How can I achieve writing beside?

Answer (score 0):

Just put 2 on the same line before writing a `LINE_SEPARATOR`. Change what's in your `writeElements` to something like this:

```
private void writeElements(Object... elements) throws IOException {
    if (fileStream != null) {
        for (int index = 1; index < elements.length + 1; index++) {
            String address = elements[index - 1].toString();
            fileStream.write(address);
            if(index % 2 == 0) fileStream.write(LINE_SEPARATOR);
            else fileStream.write(DATA_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
Object[] elements = new Object[4];
elements[0] = "here";
elements[1] = "are";
elements[2] = "some";
elements[3] = "words";

writeElements(elements);
```

When opening the file:

```
here,are
some,words
```

Comment: Still no...its the same

Comment: Ok Just did one last edit. Code testing and verified, works for me.

Comment: still same problem... the output i get is -
DeviceA -85 

DS:DA:AB:2B:B4:AE

DecviceB -90

Comment: Updated to show you my test case. If it doesn't work, there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, why do you have no commas? It's a CSV file.

Comment: The code which I have pasted is the code which I use... Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in your code that pops out as an immediate problem. Can you try changing the file to something else? Like "test.txt" and see what happens? Could have something to do with what you are using to look at the file.

Comment: If the comment I just added above doesn't work, I'm sorry to say that I'm not really sure.